# Maximizing concurrency in externally IO bound applications (JVM)

Tags: java, concurrency, architecture, nonblocking

I have a class of problems that can be stated as follows:

Imagine a completely horizontally scalable service call it **Service A**, i.e. from the consumer's perspective service A can handle a infinite # of concurrent requests without fail over (either through extremely good auto-scaling policies with no single data layer contention or extremely tolerant request queues)

A CLI program **(the CLI)** must iterate over an relatively large file (say 10GB), each line in the file contains a request for **Service A**. The CLI program construct these requests as it iterates through the file, and forwards the request to Service A. For each request, as Service A responds the CLI parses the response in a short-lived method

Although Service A is extremely good at handling concurrency, each request is synchronous and may take arbitrarily long period of time.

The immediate thought is: we can utilize a ThreadPool but each worker thread would then be IO bound - not much heap/CPU utilization would be seen on the CLI but the CLI would still appear slow

What is the preferred non-blocking architecture to handle this class of problems to maximize concurrency?

Comment: I would be looking into the `nio` package, such as using [AsynchronousSocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html). Honestly I haven't read very carefully, but at first glance it seems like the right path.

Comment: is this a service over HTTP? What is the average time taken per request? what kind of data is this? is it json? is it compressed binary? is it a kind of batch job that runs for hours? what is the overall SLA for completion and what is the total time taken now?

Comment: Yea I guess the idea would be over HTTP (though I would abstract that away and say some kind of "TCP socket connection", not necessarily hypertext or tied to any layer 7 protocol

A use case could be processing time = 10 - 50 seconds, but infinitely parallel 

I think the `java.nio.*` package was a good start, a single thread managing multiple channels would've been a pretty good start

With that I've found for HTTP Apache Http Async was pretty useful

Answer (score 0):

I would reevaluate your requirements. It looks like you need to process a large file and execute a batch operation over it with each record potentially taking a long time to process. IMHO using CLI for this is not ideal due to:

- The parallelism is limited by a single CLI client process
- A failure of the CLI process would lose all the progress
- You mentioned that each request is synchronous, but can take unpredictable time. How do you set the timeout for such requests? The standard solution is to use heartbeating from the request implementation handler to learn about failures quickly.
- While you stated that the downstream service has unlimited throughput in the real life you want to be able to control the rate of calls to it independently on how many files are being processed simultaneously.

I would recommend using an orchestration system like [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/02_use_cases/06_batch_job) to implement your business logic in a fault tolerant and scalable way. For example it would allow processing the file in parallel from multiple worker processes and deal with retries and long running operations easily. It is already used inside Uber for multiple scenarios similar to yours.